# how to make ffmpeg output frames at correct rate down to millisecond

Tags: ffmpeg, ppm, image2pipe

using ffmpeg, i am fetching frames from udp stream (hd264 at 25 fps) using following command:

ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i udp://231.20.20.146:2005 -fflags nobuffer -r 1 -preset ultrafast -vf scale=432:243 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm pipe:1

at the other end of the pipe i am running a very simple binary which outputs the time at which it receives a frame.

however, even though i specify fps 1, frames enter the pipe with some delay, with 100-200ms delay.

what causes this delay? is it the decoding of the frames and encoding of ppm image? and how can i force ffmpeg to send images at least at the correct distance between each other, so that each frame would arrive exactly 1000ms after previous frame?

ps. the first 6 frames are buffered and enter the pipe almost at once. here is an example of recorded ms values :

5350
5368
5385
5493
5599
5676
5785
6221
7243
8235
9218
10219
11227
12268
13268
14242
15288
16219
17297
18222
19284
20272

Comment: Try with `-re` before `-i`

Comment: from docs: The FFmpeg's "-re" flag means to "Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab device." i.e. if you wanted to stream a video file, then you would want to use this, otherwise it might stream it too fast (it attempts to stream at line speed by default). My guess is you typically don't want to use this flag when streaming from a live device, ever.

Comment: i tried though just to check, with same result

Comment: Well, it didn't work, but the caveat applies to input from a live stream. If you are fetching a saved stream over a network then ffmpeg can read it at a faster speed. Try with `-vf realtime`

Answer (score 0):

closest to solution was using fps in video filter:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100000 -i udp://231.20.20.146:2005  -r 8 -fflags nobuffer -preset ultrafast -vf "scale=432:243, fps=8, realtime" -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm pipe:1
```

there still are some occurences with 1-3 ms off, but that might be due to cpu scaling or converting stream to ppm..